# How to execute multi-line statements within Python's own debugger (PDB)

Tags: python, debugging, multiline, pdb

So I am running a Python script within which I am calling Python's debugger, PDB by writing:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

(iPython's version of PDB, though for the matter I don't think it makes a difference; I use it for the colored output only).

Now, when I get to the debugger I want to execute a multi-line statement such as an if clause or a for loop but as soon as I type

```
if condition:
```

and hit the return key, I get the error message `*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 1)`

How can one execute multi-line statements within PDB? If not possible is there a way around this to still executing an if clause or a for loop?

Answer (score 325):

You could do this while in pdb to launch a temporary interactive Python session with all the local variables available:

```
(pdb) !import code; code.interact(local=vars())
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
```

When you're done, use Ctrl-D to return to the regular pdb prompt.

Just don't hit Ctrl-C, that will terminate the entire pdb session.

Comment: It seems the same can be achieved using the pdb `interact` command ([as I learned from this bug tracker message](http://bugs.python.org/msg215963)).

Comment: Why is the `!` needed in the `import` statement?

Comment: It's probably not needed, but I have a habit of prefixing all Python statements in pdb with `!`, to avoid accidents.  E.g. `c = 42` in pdb would *continue* execution instead of assigning to variable `c`.

Comment: @MariusGedminas the most frustrating thing with PDB! Would be nice if *their* commands had to be prefixed...

Comment: Note: Ctrl-D seems to be the right way to exit `interact` too, but it does not play well with Spyder for me.

Comment: If you have to stick on python 2 for some reason (Okay, I know it is a bad idea), `interact` doesn't work but this works.

Comment: @SanoberSayyed Ctrl+D is a very Linux thing.  Are you on Windows?  Try Ctrl+Z, followed by Enter.

Answer (score 164):

In python3 `ipdb` (and `pdb`) have a command called [interact](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-interact). It can be used to:

> Start an interactive interpreter (using the [code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#module-code) module) whose global namespace contains all the (global and local) names found in the current scope.

To use it, simply enter `interact` at the pdb prompt. Among other things, it's useful for applying code spanning multiple lines, and also for avoiding accidental triggering of other pdb commands.

Comment: It gives me "NameError: name 'interact' is not defined" when doing that.

Comment: @jason version 3.2 or higher

Comment: That explains. I was in python 2.7.

Comment: Careful this actually threw an error that interact could is not defined and exited the process

Comment: Avoid the `interact` command.  It just puts you in a regular Python REPL.  I would use iPython embedding as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49624002/1175053

Comment: I think suggesting to avoid `interact` is a suggestion too strong. 90% this is all I ever need, and it's a lot easier to type than `from IPython import embed; embed()`

Comment: Best answer! Simplicity always wins

Comment: Great! But how do I get out of the interact mode?

Comment: @Calimo to exit interactive mode just perform a `CTRL + D`

Answer (score 60):

My recommendation is to use IPython embedding.

```py
ipdb> from IPython import embed; embed()
```

Comment: If you're having value is not defined error in list comprehension, try to use from IPython `import embed; embed(user_ns=locals())`.

Comment: this works far better for me than the accepted answer. For example - it allows proper editing of multiline - like going back up a few lines and fixing something, so you don't have to rewrite your entire multi-line expression again... 
I'm passing the locals as @fx-kirin suggested.

Comment: I set up an alias so I can just type "e" to activate this in pdb: in `.pbdrc`, put `alias e !from IPython import embed; embed(user_ns=locals())`. In case you're using pdbpp (pdb++), do not put it in `.pbdrc.py`, it will not work - create a `.pbdrc` file. 

I prefer this to `interact()` because it works even when I'm copy & pasting code that ends up having the "wrong" set of indentations.

Comment: Can you continue the code execution afterwards? I can never work out a smooth exit

Answer (score 39):

Inside the Python (2.7.1) interpreter or debugger (import pdb), you can execute a multi-line statement with the following syntax.

```
for i in range(5): print("Hello"); print("World"); print(i)
```

Note: When I'm inside the interpreter, I have to hit return twice before the code will execute.  Inside the debugger, however, I only have to hit return once.

Comment: It doesn't allow running anything deeper than one level.

Answer (score 7):

There is the special case if you want a couple of commands be executed when hitting a break point. Then there is the debugger command `commands`. It allows you to enter multiple lines of commands and then end the whole sequence with the `end` key word. More with `(pdb) help commands`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can do this, that'd be a great feature for ipdb though. You can use list comprehensions of course, and execute simple multi-line expressions like:

```
if y == 3: print y; print y; print y;
```

You could also write some functions beforehand to do whatever it is you need done that would normally take multiple lines.