# List comprehension scope error from Python debugger

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, list-comprehension

In debugging my code, I want to use a list comprehension. However, it seems I cannot evaluate a list comprehension from the debugger when I'm inside a function.

I am using Python 3.4.

**Script contents**:

```
$ cat test.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

def foo():
    x = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]

    print(x)

foo()
```

**Interactive debugging:**

```
$ python3 -mpdb test.py                                                                                                                                           
> /tmp/test.py(3)<module>()
-> def foo():
(Pdb) step
> /tmp/test.py(8)<module>()
-> foo()
(Pdb) 
--Call--
> /tmp/test.py(3)foo()
-> def foo():
(Pdb) 
> /tmp/test.py(4)foo()
-> x = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
(Pdb) 
> /tmp/test.py(6)foo()
-> print(x)
(Pdb) p [x for _ in range(1)]
*** NameError: name 'x' is not defined
(Pdb) p x
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

Why is `x` unknown to the list comprehension?  How could I evaluate a list comprehension from the debugger, or achieve an equivalent behaviour?  Is this a bug, or is it some sort of fundamental limitation to the debugger?

Comment: Simpler example: `p (lambda: x)()`

Comment: The lambda pointer gave me an idea, and I found that the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5967241/974555) apply equally here.

Comment: Ah, that `code.interact(locals=vars())` does exactly what my `eval` hack does.

Comment: Oh, and `pdb` even has an `interact` command, cool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPython debugger raises \`NameError: name ... is not defined\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164288/ipython-debugger-raises-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: I just run `globals().update(locals())` before running list comprehension and it solves the issue.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In Python 3, you have to use the `interact` command in pdb before you can access any non-global variables due to a change in the way comprehensions are implemented.

```
>>> def foo(): [][0]
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in foo
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> import pdb;pdb.pm()
> <stdin>(1)foo()
(Pdb) x = 4
(Pdb) [x for _ in range(2)]
*** NameError: name 'x' is not defined
(Pdb) interact
*interactive*
>>> [x for _ in range(2)]
[4, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: and for python2?

Comment: In Python 2 you don't have to do anything, it just works

Comment: Had this problem for years, and thought it was generally just a bug that never got fixed.

Comment: @DaveLiu Or *is* it a bug that never got fixed? The `interact` trick is refered [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue38970#msg357840) as a workaround.

Comment: I tried `interact` during a set_trace of qt app, and the shell become unresponsive, only responding with `QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running` whenever I pressed enter.

Comment: how to get out of interact mode but still in pdb?

Answer (score 14):

`pdb` seems to be running the code with:

```
eval(compiled_code, globals(), locals())
```

(or maybe even just `eval(string, globals(), locals())`).

Unfortunately, on compilation Python doesn't know of the local variables. This doesn't matter normally:

```
import dis
```

```
dis.dis(compile("x", "", "eval"))
#>>>   1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
#>>>               3 RETURN_VALUE
```

but when another scope is introduced, such as with a list comprehension of `lambda`, this compiles badly:

```
dis.dis(compile("(lambda: x)()", "", "eval"))
#>>>   1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <lambda> at 0x7fac20708d20, file "", line 1>)
#>>>               3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<lambda>')
#>>>               6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
#>>>               9 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
#>>>              12 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
# The code of the internal lambda
dis.dis(compile("(lambda: x)()", "", "eval").co_consts[0])
#>>>   1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
#>>>               3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note how that's a `LOAD_GLOBAL` where `x` is in the local scope.

---

Here's a totally stupid hack to get around it:

```
(Pdb) eval("(lambda: x)()", vars())
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Aah, and the reason it does work when it's on a module-level, is because `x` is not in `locals()`.  I didn't get that at first.

Answer (score 11):

**Running List Comprehensions that depend on Outer Context in the Debugger**

The accepted solution did not work for me. Or, maybe my setting differs in a way I cannot distinguish from the question's setting. But, this is where google led me when I searched for a solution to running list comprehensions that depend on objects outside of the comprehension's scope. So, here's a solution for other folks with the same problem. Run the following line in the debugger.

```
globals().update(locals())
```

Then, your list comprehension should run without any problems. [Source.](https://jss367.github.io/debugging-python-list-comprehensions.html)