# VS Code: python debugger unable to evaluate `[test for test in range(10) if x]`

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

EDIT: I tested a few more things. It looks like this error only occurs with my company's internal python executable, not `/bin/python` or an anaconda install. Would like to vote to close this.

If I break into the VS code python debugger (this is debugpy v1.6.6) and in the debug console run:

```
x = 1
[test for test in range(10) if x]
```

On the second line I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? Possibly related posts:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2110
- [List comprehension scope error from Python debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149168/list-comprehension-scope-error-from-python-debugger)

The first link suggests the issue was resolved in ~2018, however I am experiencing it today on my work machine with version 2023.2 of the VS code python extension. Any ideas?

Info:

- VS code version: 1.79.2
- debugpy version: 1.6.6
- python: 3.8

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am not able to replicate. Perhaps a gif showing exactly what you're doing in the interactive debugger might help?

Comment: It seems like you are running that line only. Line 2 of your code is line 1 in the traceback.

Comment: I switched the version of vscode and python extension to be the same as yours, [and there was no problem, and it can be executed normally](https://imgur.com/q5oyEq9.png).
You can try to upgrade the versions of vscoe and python extensions. The latest versions are [vscode 1.80](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80) and [Python 2023.12.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).

Comment: If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: There is no answer. See my edit.