# Python debugger PDB nested for loops SyntaxError: invalid syntax(<stdin>, line 1)

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

When I run a script with PDB, I find that I have to put for loops into one line to run correctly.  When I try to nest for loops as shown below, I get a SyntaxError.  How can I run nested for loops??

```
(pdb) for input in range(20): print input*2
0
2
4
...
36
38

(pdb) for input in range(20): for output in range(10): print input*2
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax(<stdin>, line 1)
```

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967241/how-to-execute-multi-line-statements-within-pythons-own-debugger-pdb

Answer (score 2):

This does not have to do with pdb, but is just python (this fails in the normal python repl).

The grammar for a for statement is defined as:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

where suite is either a list of simple statements or a newline and a list of statements. the for statment is a compound statement so it cannot be inlined like that.

Comment: And I can't do newlines in PDB, so how do I iterate an operation over two variables in PDB?

Comment: run `help commands` in pdb, this is most likely the command you are looking for.