# How to paste multiple lines to an ipdb shell in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am working with python and ipdb debugger.
Let's say is set some breaking point in some line in a python file.
Now, after running the python file, the program stops at the breakpoint.
I want to be able to paste multiple lines to the ipdb shell.
Now i get an error, if trying to paste mutiple lines.
How can i paste mutiple lines?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute multi-line statements within Python's own debugger (PDB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967241/how-to-execute-multi-line-statements-within-pythons-own-debugger-pdb)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot simply paste them. You have to use `;` to indicate indentation. For example:

```
for i in range(10): print i; print("hello")
```

would be equivalent to

```
for i in range(10): 
    print(i)
    print("hello")
```

If you want the `hello` out of the loop, then you need to use `;;` instead:

```
for i in range(10): print i;; print("hello")
```